# Get role list with associated users in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, ninject

I have a role. How can I find the list of users which have that role?

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(roleManager.RoleList.ToList());
}
```

In this method I take the list of roles there have the user's `UsersId`. Now how to link it with my `UserModel` to take the `UserName`?

I am not so good in the LINQ, and can't find a good idea

In the result I want to make a table in the view

```
foreach (RoleModel role in Model)
{
            <tr>
                <td>@role.Id</td>
                <td>@role.Name</td>
                <td>@role.Description</td>
                <td>
                    @if (role.Users == null || role.Users.Count == 0)
                    {
                        @: Нет пользователей в этой роли
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //User name which have that role
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
}
```

Comment: If you have the userManager then there is a method `userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync`.

Comment: I removed my answer as I neglected that you were using ASP.NET MVC rather than Core. If you have UserManager then I would have thought it would offer a method similar to GetUserInRoleAsync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the miss design of **ASP.NET Identity** that there is no short cut way of getting the list of **Roles** with its associated **Users**. But you can get with some extra effort as follow:

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
   public string RoleId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public List<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public ViewResult Index()
{
    List<RoleViewModel> rolesWithUsers = new List<RoleViewModel>();

    List<ApplicationRole> applicationRoles = RoleManager.Roles.Include(r => r.Users).ToList();

    foreach (ApplicationRole applicationRole in applicationRoles)
    {
        RoleViewModel roleViewModel = new RoleViewModel()
        {
                RoleId = applicationRole.Id,
                Name = applicationRole.Name,
                Description = applicationRole.Description
        };

        List<UserViewModel> usersByRole = UserManager.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == applicationRole.Id))
                .Select(u => new UserViewModel
                {
                    UserId = u.Id,
                    UserName = u.UserName
                }).ToList();
        roleViewModel.Users = usersByRole;

        rolesWithUsers.Add(roleViewModel);
    }

    return View(rolesWithUsers);
}
```

Now each role will have its associated users.

Note : From performance standpoint, above solution is not a good option. That's why its always better to use **ASP.NET identity** entities with your own `DbContext` instead of default `IdenityStote`.

Comment: If i use in view `@using Domain.Entity @model IEnumerable<RoleModel>`, in foreach role have the property Users which have only userId and role Id

Comment: @remk93 Please see my updated answer. In View please use `@using Domain.ViewModels @model IEnumerable<RoleViewModel>`

Comment: thak you, it work right, and yes you right it not the best option.But now I just learn how it work, and for me it's not bad decision.