# Create a left join query without navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would achieve this goal using EFCore method syntax

- Given an user retrieve all roles and set IsInRole = 1 if the given user has the role, otherwise 0

in tsql is something like

```
CREATE TABLE USER(USERNAME VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE ROLE(ROLENAME VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE USERROLE(USERNAME VARCHAR(200), ROLENAME VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO USER VALUES('LELU');
INSERT INTO ROLE VALUES('ROLE1');
INSERT INTO ROLE VALUES('ROLE2');
INSERT INTO USERROLE VALUES('LELU', 'ROLE1');

SELECT R.ROLENAME, CASE WHEN T.ROLEID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ISINROLE
FROM ROLE R
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT UR.ROLENAME ROLEID
  FROM USERROLE UR
  WHERE UR.USERNAME='LELU'
) T ON T.ROLEID=R.ROLENAME 

ROLENAME                ISINROLE
-------------------------------------
ROLE1                   1
ROLE2                   0
```

I would like to achive this goal using EF core without navigation properties.

I have the following entities

```
public class User 
{
    [Key]
    public string Username {get; set;}
}

public class Role 
{
    [Key]
    public string Rolename {get; set;}
}

public class UserRole 
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Rolename {get; set;}
}

where UserRole (Username, Rolename) are primary keys

public class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Role> Roles {get; set;}
    public DbSet<UserRole> UsersRoles {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

I do some research online but i didn't find anything that can accomplish a left join without navigation properties.

How can I achive this goal **without** using **navigation property** neither injecting **raw query** in EFCore?

Comment: Sorry, but why wouldn't you use navigation properties? Mapping relationships to allow EF to build queries is the whole point of using Entity Framework. Asking "How can I do it without navigation properties or injecting SQL" is like asking "how can I run a marathon without moving my legs?" The tools are there to be used, what reason is there to avoid them?

Comment: I agree with you but in this particular case I can't modify "User" and "Role" classes. Because of that I'm trying to achive the this goal without navigation property.
Furthermore I am learning Entity Framework so I was wonder about if I can implement a left join without navigation property

Comment: If you don't want to / can't use navigation properties, then there is nothing in common with EF (Core). You can search general LINQ for left outer join syntax - there are many examples of the "official" pattern (with both query and method syntax). Btw, method syntax (what you call " lambda query") for joins is a real pain and quite unreadable, so if you can't use navigation properties, at least use query syntax - it would be much closer to the SQL query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible without navigation properties. It's not pretty by any stretch and depending on what details you want from the associated entities it will get a lot uglier. However, to get a list of Roles with a flag for whether the provided user is assigned to them or not:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var roles = context.Roles
        .SelectMany(r => context.UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.RoleName == r.RoleName 
             && ur.UserName == userName).DefaultIfEmpty(),
             (r, ur) => new
             {
                 RoleName = r.RoleName,
                 IsInRole = ur != null
             }).ToList();
}
```

That would return each role, and whether the provided `userName` value was assigned to that role using a Left join via the `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: Thank you Steve Py. I've tried your solution and it works. As you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715309/11084254 ASP.NET Identity doesn't use navigation property inside IdentityUser / IdentityRole / UsersRoles entities. Because of that I wrote this question with a simplified sample of the tables I have to use. Anyway, thank you! This solution works!

Answer (score 1):

Although LINQ query syntax is generally disliked, I believe it fits the scenario of joining entities without navigation properties very nicely.

```cs
var query = 
    from role in context.Roles
    join userRole in context.UserRoles on userRole.RoleName equals role.RoleName
    select new 
    {
        ...
    };
```

Albeit the left join is not as nice.

```cs
var query = 
    from role in context.Roles
    join userRole in context.UserRoles on userRole.RoleName equals role.RoleName into ur
    from userRole in ur.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        RoleName = role.RoleName,
        IsInRole = userRole != null
    };
```

As a bonus, in case you need to do multiple joins, with LINQ query syntax you only have to add a single additional line describing the join.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the multiple join?  I inherited a db with about 100 tables and none has FK.  So no navigation property.  Now I have a task where I need to combine about 10 tables to get data.  Looks like I have to use multiple left joins in the query syntax and it's soooooo ugly to the point it's not doable.